# Selecting text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to highlight a pull-quote in a story in a rails app. I found this code in another question and modified it slightly to work with rails. Here's what I'm doing in my view:

```
<%= content_for :jquery do %>
      $.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {
          var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");

          return this.each(function () {
              this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + matched + "</span>";});
          });
      };
      $('p').highlight('<%=j @story.pull_quote %>', 'highlight');
    <% end %>
```

But, it doesn't seem to work. I'm really bad with javascript.

Comment: What are you trying to replace? That function doesn't tell us much.

Comment: A string. You can't tell that from the function?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. A *string* is not a *regex*. Even if you call `RegExp()` with it. For example, what if the *string* contains regex literals.

Comment: It should match a literal string, regardless, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
          this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + str + "</span>");
```